# Discord bot not detecting when I deafen

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Basically, I want my discord bot to move me to AFK as soon as I deafen but it does nothing with the code I have. I have tried using console.log on the if statement but still nothing.

Code:

```js
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldState, newState) => {
    let memchange = newState.member;
    if (memchange.selfDeaf) {
        memchange.setChannel(afkchannelid);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the GUILD_VOICE_STATES intent ?

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: ['GUILD_VOICE_STATES'] });
```

Comment: I didn't until you mentioned it. added it and it looks like this now

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_VOICE_STATES"] });

still not working tho